# Gradle Test Fails in CircleCI- Could not find symbols for Lombok Generated Code

Tags: spring-boot, lombok, circleci

I have a Spring Boot application with Gradle. I tried upgrading to Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE. I also had to upgrade Gradel Wrapper in `gradle-wrapper.properties` like this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-bin.zip
```

My code uses Lombok 1.18.2

Locally, my application tests runs correctly. However, CircleCI build fails, like this.

## !/bin/bash -eo pipefail

gradle test

> Task :compileJava
>   /home/circleci/repo/src/main/java/guru/springframework/spring5webfluxrest/bootstrap/Bootstrap.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
>               categoryRepository.save(Category.builder()
>                                               ^
>     symbol:   method builder()
>     location: class Category
>   /home/circleci/repo/src/main/java/guru/springframework/spring5webfluxrest/bootstrap/Bootstrap.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
>               categoryRepository.save(Category.builder()
>                                               ^
>     symbol:   method builder()
>     location: class Category
>   /home/circleci/repo/src/main/java/guru/springframework/spring5webfluxrest/bootstrap/Bootstrap.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
>               categoryRepository.save(Category.builder()
>                                               ^
>     symbol:   method builder()
>     location: class Category
>   /home/circleci/repo/src/main/java/guru/springframework/spring5webfluxrest/bootstrap/Bootstrap.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
>               categoryRepository.save(Category.builder()
>                                               ^
>     symbol:   method builder()
>     location: class Category
>   /home/circleci/repo/src/main/java/guru/springframework/spring5webfluxrest/bootstrap/Bootstrap.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
>               categoryRepository.save(Category.builder()
>                                               ^
>     symbol:   method builder()
>     location: class Category
>   /home/circleci/repo/src/main/java/guru/springframework/spring5webfluxrest/bootstrap/Bootstrap.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
>               vendorRepository.save(Vendor.builder()
>                                           ^
>     symbol:   method builder()
>     location: class Vendor
>   /home/circleci/repo/src/main/java/guru/springframework/spring5webfluxrest/bootstrap/Bootstrap.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
>               vendorRepository.save(Vendor.builder()
>                                           ^
>     symbol:   method builder()
>     location: class Vendor
>   /home/circleci/repo/src/main/java/guru/springframework/spring5webfluxrest/bootstrap/Bootstrap.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
>               vendorRepository.save(Vendor.builder()
>                                           ^
>     symbol:   method builder()
>     location: class Vendor
>   /home/circleci/repo/src/main/java/guru/springframework/spring5webfluxrest/bootstrap/Bootstrap.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
>               vendorRepository.save(Vendor.builder()
>                                           ^
>     symbol:   method builder()
>     location: class Vendor
>   /home/circleci/repo/src/main/java/guru/springframework/spring5webfluxrest/bootstrap/Bootstrap.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
>               vendorRepository.save(Vendor.builder()
>                                           ^
>     symbol:   method builder()
>     location: class Vendor
>   10 errors
>
> Task :compileJava FAILED

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Exited with code 1
```

Please help.

Comment: are you able to execute `gradle build` or `gradle test` without issues locally? I get the same error locally when I run `gradle build` or `test` locally but it works if I use `./gradlew build` or `./gradlew test` locally.

Answer (score 0):

Try change `gradle` and use `./gradlew` under the `steps:` section in the `config.yml` as the template below:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/postgres:9.4

    working_directory: ~/repo

    environment:
      # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
      TERM: dumb

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-

      - run: ./gradlew dependencies # <-- changed from `gradle dependencies`

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}

      # run tests!
      - run: ./gradlew test # <-- changed from `gradle test`
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was add "annotationProcessor" to build.gradle dependencies (it was not building locally either).

```
dependencies {
   compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
   annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use annotationProcessor `'org.projectlombok:lombok'` in build.gradle in dependencies. It will work smooth.